# Mail through MVC not displaying images for different IE

Tags: .net

Sending Mail is a Success with the code

```
 LinkedResource theEmailImage = new LinkedResource(path);
  theEmailImage.ContentId = "myImageID";
  theEmailImage.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
  htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);
```

but the image is being displayed in chrome not in IE .
it  displays:
[the x icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZGMH.png)

Answer (score 0):

adding the following helped me:

```
 theEmailImage.ContentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg; ;
          theEmailImage.ContentType.Name = theEmailImage.ContentId;
```